# How to get data in Angular 2 service with Mlab

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mlab

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor() { 
    console.log("Users service initialized");
  }

  getUsers(){
    //Mlab URL
    //Example: mongodb://user:password@ds129038.mlab.com:29038/database_name
  }

}
```

Hi, i'm looking the way to get users in angular 2 service from a database in MLAB. How could I receive them and iterate results? 
Regards,

Comment: You might want to try working through mLab's MEAN stack tutorial which uses AngularJS (aka Angular 2): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api

Answer (score 0):

1. In your app folder make a new folder and name it "server"
2. Inside "server" folder make two new folders and name the "models", and "routes"
3. In models folder create a javascript file and name it same as your collection name in mlab/mongodb. Example "datacollection1.js"
4. Inside datacollection1.js paste the following code:

   const mongoose = require('mongoose');

   const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

   const datacollection1Schema = new Schema({
       varone: String,
       vartwo: String,
       varthree: String,
       varfour: String
   });

   module.exports = mongoose.model('datacollection1', herodataSchema, 'datacollection1class');
5. Inside "routes" folder create a file and name it "api.js"
6. Paste the following code in api.js

   const express = require('express');
   const router = express.Router();
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');
   const Datacollection1class = require('../models/datacollection1');

   const db = "mongodb://:@ds155201.mlab.com:<12345>/";
   mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
   mongoose.connect(db, function(err){
       if(err) {
           console.log("Error: " + err);
       }
   });

   //Get all data
   router.get('/datacollection1class', function(req, res) {
       console.log("Get request for datacollection1class");
       Datacollection1class.find({})
       .exec(function(err, datacollection1class){
           if(err) {
               console.log("Error retrieving datacollection1class.");
           } else {
               res.json(datacollection1class);
           }
       })
   });

   //retrieve data by id
   router.get('/datacollection1class/:id', function(req, res) {
       console.log("Get request for sigle document");
       Datacollection1class.findById(req.params.id)
       .exec(function(err, datacollection1classsingle){
           if(err) {
               console.log("Error retrieving datacollection1classsingle.");
           }
           else
           {
               res.json(datacollection1classsingle);
           }
       })
   });

   //Add a single new documemt
   router.post('/datacollection1classsingle', function(req, res){
       console.log('Post a data set');
       var newDatacollection1classsingle = new Datacollection1class();
       newDatacollection1classsingle.varone = req.body.varone;
       newDatacollection1classsingle.vartwo = req.body.vartwo;
       newDatacollection1classsingle.varthree = req.body.varthree;
       newDatacollection1classsingle.varfour = req.body.varfour;
       newDatacollection1classsingle.save(function(err, insertedDatacollection1classsingle){
           if (err) {
               console.log('Error saving new hero data: '+err);
           } else {
               res.json(insertedDatacollection1classsingle);
           }
       });
   });

   //Update existing document
   router.put('/hatacollection1class/:id', function(req, res) {
       console.log('Update a video');
       Datacollection1class.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
       {
           $set: {
               varone: req.body.varone,
               vartwo: req.body.vartwo,
               varthree: req.body.varthree,
               varfour: req.body.varfour
           }
       },
       {
           new:true
       },
       function(err, updatedDatacollection1classsingle) {
           if(err){
               res.send("Error updating Datacollection1class by id : "+err);
           } else {
               res.json(updatedDatacollection1classsingle);
           }
       });
   });

   // Delete a document
   router.delete('/datacollection1class/:id', function(req, res) {
       console.log('Deleting a datacollection1class');
       Datacollection1class.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err, deletedDatacollection1classsingle){
           if (err) {
               res.send("Error deleting Datacollection1class by id: "+err);
           } else {
               res.json(deletedDatacollection1classsingle);
           }
       });
   });
7. Go to command prompt and using angular CLI create a class. Make sure Angular CLI is installed on your machine. Type in command prompt in your app folder

   ng generate class datacollection1class

and hit enter. This will create a file named "datacollection1class.ts"

8. Inside datacollection1class.ts type the following code:

   export class Datacollection1class {
       _id: string;
       varone: string;
       vartwo: string;
       varthree: string;
       varfour: string;
   }
9. You are all set. Now on your command prompt type:

   ng build
10. Then on your command prompt type:

    node server
11. Go to the browser and run "http://localhost:4200/api/datacollection1class" or if you have the id of the document, then "http://localhost:4200/api/datacollection1class/59305a02734d1d5068f2414e" or tey running it using postman

> Feel free to ask questions. upvote if you liked the help.